# Problema llamando funcion javascript no devuelve resultado generado por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar, resulta que quiero llamar a una funcion la cual despues de hacer un insert en mysql devuelve el id, eso lo hace perfecto, pero mi funcion nunca logra recibir el resultado pese que el id por consola sale correctamente, que hago mal?

Ahora si en vez de llamar la funcion la pego debajo si hacer otra funcion anda. Como que no espera el regreso de la funcion y sigue de largo 
Mil gracias

log de console de ejemplo me da

index.php?mod=documentos&nuevo:272 Documento id undefined
index.php?mod=documentos&nuevo:305 El id generado es 12

```
  var idDocumento=0;

   function newfun(){
        var termino=false;                          
        idDocumento=SaveDoc();   //<-- nunca regresa el id creado no entiendo porque sale undefined
        if (idDocumento==0){
            console.log ("No pudo guarda el doc.");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log ("Documento id "+idDocumento);

            if (termino==true){
                location.reload();
            }               
        }
      }



    function SaveDoc(){

    //Grabo el documento
    var claveingresado=0;
    var  sigue=0;
    if($(seguimiento).is(':checked')){
        sigue=1;
    }

    var parametros = {
            "valorCaja1" : $('#asunto').val(),
            "valorCaja2" : $('#nota').val(),
            "valorCaja3" : sigue
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'grabo-doc.php',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#recargado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    $("#recargado").html(response);
                    idDocumento=response;  //id creado
                    console.log("El id generado es "+idDocumento);        //<----- aca lo muestra perfecto
                    return idDocumento;   //<---deberia regresar ese valor
            }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Al inicio de `function SaveDoc()` declara la variable igualada a cero: `var idDocument=0;`. Luego, pon el return fuera del `success`, al final de la función, antes de cerrar la última llave. Aquí: `}); return idDocumento; }`. Veamos qué pasa.

Comment: El problema es por el ajax  como decia dddenis, gracias por tu ayuda tambien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es qué tu función `SaveDoc()` no retorna nada y el valor que necesitas es resuelto asíncronamente, por lo tanto necesitas resolver el problema asíncronamente. Tienes varias opciones, los clásicos [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), las [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y los [observables](http://reactivex.io/).

> Con callbacks sería así:

```
function SaveDoc(callback) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(res) {
            // ...
            callback(res);
        }
    });
}

SaveDoc((id) => {
    // Tú código...
});
```

> Con promesas sería así:

```
function SaveDoc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            success: function(res) {
                // ...
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}

SaveDoc().then((id) => {
    // Tú código...
});
```

> Con observables sería así:

```
function SaveDoc() {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        // ...
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            success: function(res) {
                // ...
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}

SaveDoc().subscribe((id) => {
    // Tú código...
});
```

La opción más común suele ser los callbacks y las promesas (aunque ojo con la compatibilidad), los observables requieres de librería externa y para el problema que tienes no creo que te sea necesario.

Comment: Gracias dddenis , la verdad que no sabia nada de esos manejos, estoy aprendiendo y con la forma callback quedo perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Denis una pregunta mas si tuviese que hacer esa misma llamada y por ejemplo pasarle un parametro como seria? Suponete que para que se ejecute el ajax necesita recibir un id para pasar al php como parametros, podria hacer

```
introducir el código aquí
    function SaveDoc(PARAMETRO,callback) {
     // ...
     $.ajax({
       // ...
     success: function(res) {
        // ...
        callback(res);
        }
      });
      }

    SaveDoc(PARAMETRO,(id) => {
          // Tú código...
      });
```

ES correcto algo asi?

Comment: Sí, estaría bien.